# How to send table-data to a modal-form, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, html-table, modal-dialog

How can I show an `array` or `objects` in a `modal-form` using `JavaScript`? Let me show some code snippets first. The page is written in `PHP`, but the `HTML` result is shown.

First, I have a `container` which I want to use as `modal-form`.

```
<div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
  <div id="textplayer">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `text` in the `container` should be replaced with the `data` from following `table`.

```
<tr onclick="on('FP0001')">
  <td class="FP0001">
    FP0001
  </td>
  <td class="FP0001">
    Jimmy 
  </td>
  <td class="FP0001">
    Right Back 
  </td>
</tr>
```

The `JavaScript` `style-display` elements make the `container` visible or hidden.

```
<script>
function on(classPlayer) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(classPlayer);

  document.getElementById("textplayer").innerHTML = x[2].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

I guess, I'm just lucky. However so far everything seems to work well.

`var x` is used to show the `value` of `x[2]` inside the `modal-form`.

This is as far as I got. Every change in the code makes it impossible to use the `onclick` method from the `<tr>`. Or better said, everything stops the `container` from showing by `onclick`.

I've tried to add some `code` after the `var x=` statement in `JavaScript`, but then the `container` won't show up anymore. Many other things I've tried and all gave the same problem.

Where does it go wrong? Hopefully somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this `document.getElementById("textplayer").innerHTML = x[2].innerText;`

Comment: I was trying `document.getElementById("textplayer").childNodes[2].nodeValue=x[2]c` but that doesn't work well, because outside `<p>` elements is also counted as nodes.